# if statement for MFMailComposer dosn`t work

Tags: objective-c, if-statement, uialertview, mfmailcomposer

I have a simple problem:

If i click on my mail button and there is no E-Mail address deposited i want the alertView to show up and i don`t want it to go to the Mail composer but it does.

The AlertView works but why does it goe to the MailComposer anyway?

Using X-Code, Objective C.

Here is the Code:

```
-(IBAction)sendMail {
  if ([mailIdentity isEqualToString:@""] == FALSE); {
   MFMailComposeViewController *mailController0 = [[MFMailComposeViewController    alloc]init];
   [mailController0 setMailComposeDelegate:self];
  NSString *email0 = mailIdentity;
   NSArray *emailArray0 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:email0, nil];
   [mailController0 setToRecipients:emailArray0];
[mailController0 setSubject:@"From my IPhone"];
[self presentViewController : mailController0 animated:YES completion:nil]; 
  }

if ([mailIdentity isEqualToString:@""] == TRUE) {
    UIAlertView *noMail = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"noMail"
                                                        message: @"No E-Mail address"
                                                       delegate: nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [noMail show];
}

}
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice the semicolon ; after `..g:@""] == FALSE)`**;**. It should be `..g:@""] == FALSE) {...}` . BTW, You could also write : `if(![mailIdentity isEqualToString:@""]) {...}` and `if ([mailIdentity isEqualToString:@""]) {...}`

Comment: THX. It sure was the semicolon:

Answer (score 0):

You definitely have semicolon problem here like @true said, but you may also consider that
`isEqualToString:` may be tricky here if you compare it to empty string. You may also want to use:

```
NSString *str; //if you change it to NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] init]; you will get diffetent if result
if([str isEqualToString:@""]) NSLog(@"this is string allocated but empty!");
if(!str) NSLog(@"this is not allocated NSString object!");
```